# Translations along vector field orbits

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $v \in H^0(X, T_X)$ be a vector field on $X$. Can this vector field be extended to an action of the group $\mathbb{G}_a(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$
$$
\rho: \mathbb{G}_a(\mathbb{C}) \times X \to X,
$$
representing "translations along vector field orbits"? In analytic category this would be $\rho(t,x)=e^{tv}x,$ where $x \in X$, is there an algebraic analog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The problem is that even if the vector field is algebraic, the associated flow is typically not algebraic.  For a simple example, let $X$ be an elliptic curve, and let $v$ be a nonzero translation-invariant vector field on $X$.  In analytic terms, if $X=\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ for a lattice $\Lambda$, then you are choosing some nonzero $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $v$ is the pushforward of the constant vector field in the direction $a$ along the quotient $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$.  So the flow along $v$ should be given by $(t,x)\mapsto x+ta$ (mod $\Lambda$).  The problem is that this map is very much not algebraic, essentially because the quotient map $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is not algebraic.  Indeed, there are no nonconstant morphisms $\mathbb{A}^1\to X$ at all, so any morphism $\rho:\mathbb{A}^1\times X\to X$ would have to be constant when restricted to $\mathbb{A}^1\times\{x\}$ for each $x\in X$.